# [ROS2] How best to conditionally include a prefix in a launch.py file

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a simple .launch.py file in ROS2 Foxy:

```
def generate_launch_description():
    n = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='my_pkg',
        executable='my_node',
        prefix='some_prefix'
    )

    return launch.LaunchDescription([n])
```

However, I'd like to only add the launch prefix if some condition is True.

I have several nodes where I'd be conditionally adding the prefix, so putting an if around the all of the launch_ros.actions.Node() calls would be rather ugly.

Any advice on the cleanest way to do this? Can I use substitutions for this somehow?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363763/%5Bros2%5D-how-best-to-conditionally-include-a-prefix-in-a-launch.py-file/) by [paul.frivold](https://answers.ros.org/users/60825/paul.frivold/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2020-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit:
Just stumbled across a simpler solution in Gazebo's launch files: https://github.com/shiveshkhaitan/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/a6e395195bc878a76200fb948cc8cfce414b98fe/gazebo_ros/launch/gzclient.launch.py#L82

```
def generate_launch_description():
    use_prefix = (EnvironmentVariable('SOME_VAR', default_value='0').perform(LaunchContext()) == '1')
    n = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='my_pkg',
        executable='my_node',
        prefix=PythonExpression(['"some_prefix" if "1" == "', EnvironmentVariable('SOME_VAR', default_value='0'), '" else ""']),
    )

return launch.LaunchDescription([n])
```

Anyway, here's my original solution:

I ended up using a custom Substitution. Not sure if that's the cleanest solution, but it worked for me.

```
class ConditionalText(Substitution):
    def __init__(self, text, condition):
        self.text = text
        self.condition = condition

    def perform(self, context: 'LaunchContext') -> Text:
        if self.condition:
            return self.text
        else:
            return ''
```

Putting everything together:

```
def generate_launch_description():
    use_prefix = (EnvironmentVariable('SOME_VAR', default_value='0').perform(LaunchContext()) == '1')
    n = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='my_pkg',
        executable='my_node',
        prefix=ConditionalText('some_prefix', use_prefix),
    )

return launch.LaunchDescription([n])
```

---

Originally posted by [paul.frivold](https://answers.ros.org/users/60825/paul.frivold/) with karma: 46 on 2020-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be able to use [launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/d648e19590d425e5d38411fe83fdb3b59f56d586/launch/launch/substitutions/launch_configuration.py#L33) to achieve what you want.

For example, the following will substitute the value of the launch argument "my_arg" if it is provided or an empty string if it is not:

```
 n = launch_ros.actions.Node(
     package='my_pkg',
     executable='my_node',
     prefix=launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration('my_arg', default='')
 )
```

"my_arg" can be set from the command line like so:

```
ros2 launch my.launch.py my_arg:="some_prefix"
```

Alternatively, you can set the argument inside a launch file with [launch.actions.SetLaunchConfiguration](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/d648e19590d425e5d38411fe83fdb3b59f56d586/launch/launch/actions/set_launch_configuration.py#L31). Here's a complete example based on your question:

```
def generate_launch_description():
    set_launch_config = launch.actions.SetLaunchConfiguration(
        'my_arg', 'some_prefix'
    )
    n = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='my_pkg',
        executable='my_node',
        prefix='some_prefix'
    )

    return launch.LaunchDescription([set_launch_config, n])
```

Note, I think using SetlaunchConfiguration precludes setting the value from the command-line.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2020-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paul.frivold](https://answers.ros.org/users/60825/paul.frivold/) on 2020-10-27**:
Hey there, thanks for the answer! Sorry for being so slow to follow up.

In my case I wanted to set the prefix if a certain environment variable was set to a certain value. So using launch configuration didn't really work for me. That said, I didn't realize you could set it like that, hmm interesting.

In the end I created a custom substitution class, not sure if that's the cleanest solution, but it worked for me.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2020-10-27**:
Cool, glad you found a solution. I'm not sure how much control you have over that environment variable, but you could also use it's value directly as the prefix.

**Comment by [paul.frivold](https://answers.ros.org/users/60825/paul.frivold/) on 2020-10-27**:
Just stumbled across another possible solution from [Gazebo's Github](https://github.com/shiveshkhaitan/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/a6e395195bc878a76200fb948cc8cfce414b98fe/gazebo_ros/launch/gzclient.launch.py#L82):

```
prefix=PythonExpression(['"some_prefix" if "1" == "', EnvironmentVariable('SOME_VAR', default_value='0'), '" else ""'])
```